# Failed to upload document and metadata to sharepoint using curl ntlm

Tags: curl, sharepoint, ntlm

I use curl to upload document and document's metadata to SharePoint and failed. I ran the command in Windows
The following are the commands I have tried

Success (not including metadata)

```
C:\curl-7.59.0\src\curl -k -v --ntlm --user user1@devuat:user1pass --upload-file mark1.txt https://aura/sites/2018/DIGITAL%20AUTO/07Jul/01/mark1.txt
```

Failed (include some metadata in -F)

```
C:\curl-7.59.0\src\curl -k -v --ntlm --user user1@devuat:user1pass -F 'Account_No=123123' --upload-file mark1.txt https://aura/sites/2018/DIGITAL%20AUTO/07Jul/01/mark1.txt
```

Success but dont see any metadata in sharepoint (include some metadata in request.xml)

```
C:\curl-7.59.0\src\curl -k -v --ntlm --user user1@devuat:user1pass --data request.xml --upload-file mark1.txt https://aura/sites/2018/DIGITAL%20AUTO/07Jul/01/mark1.txt
```

The request.xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <SourceUrl>string</SourceUrl>
      <DestinationUrls>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </DestinationUrls>
      <Fields>
        <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
        <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
      </Fields>
      <Stream>base64Binary</Stream>
    </CopyIntoItems>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I got the base64Binary using below code:
 var base64 = require('file-base64');

```
base64.encode('mark1.txt', function(err, base64String) {
  console.log(base64String);
});
```